# Angular 6 - '"/node_modules/firebase/index"' has no exported member 'functions'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

> ERROR in node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(2,42):
>   error TS2305: Module '"project/node_modules/firebase/index"' has no
>   exported member 'functions'

I'm using,

```
"@angular/cdk": "^6.2.1",
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.10",
"firebase": "^4.13.1"
```

Comment: Add 
"angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.3",
 "firebase": "4.6.0"
In your package.json and hit npm install

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a problem with "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.10"
The solution is uninstall `angularfire2^5.0.0-rc.10` and install `angularfire2^5.0.0-rc.9`:

```
npm uninstall angularfire2
npm install angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.9
```

Comment: Or you can install the latest version of firebase `npm install angularfire2@latest`, right?

Comment: @VolodymyrKhmil yes you can but i'm not sure about compatibility, but sure about ```angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.9```.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: Love you, buddy!

Answer (score 3):

I was also getting the similar errors. It was obviously the version compatibility errors. I tried changing the versions of `angularfire2` amd `angular` in `package.json` but none of them work. Finally I updated the firebase to the latest version using the following command and all the errors vanished in one go. Try out this command:

```
npm install --save firebase@latest
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out: update your `firebase` to version ^5.0.3

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing some dependencies versions:

- **rxjs:** "5.5.10"
- **firebase:**  "4.12.1"
- **angularfire2:**  "5.0.0-rc.6"

Answer (score 0):

try this, it worked for me.

> npm install --save firebase @angular/fire -f

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with UserCredential... Changed the type to **any** and solved it